# Error: We only support linking to files in your own organization. Why can't I link to external files from SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, administration, sitepages

I'm not sure if this is a setting some where else. But I have added the domain to allow via the html field security.

But I cant get to add an image to link via the image web part or the Quick links etc.

I can use embed with iframe and it works.

Why can't we point to images or files that are public from SharePoint? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi @naijacoder, does below answer help you in any way? If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) & [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future. It also removes this question from "Unanswered Questions" list.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, Microsoft recently made changes to SharePoint online which does not allow using external links for images in Hero or image or quick links SharePoint web parts using "From a link" option.

I have also noticed that embedding external images using iframe and embed web part works but other web parts not working (same as you).

Images from the following domains are allowed:

1. Primary Microsoft 365 tenant domain
2. Configured multi-geo domains and vanity domains (`company.sharepoint.com`)

So, you can upload images to your SharePoint site/tenant and use those to link inside image web parts in SharePoint online OR use Stock images wherever possible.

**Similar thread**: [Error - We only support linking to files in your organization](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/error-we-only-support-linking-to-files-in-your-organization/m-p/3620126)